# Discord.js - Trying to remove a specific role from all members that have that role

Tags: discord.js

Trying to remove a specific role from all members that have that role, return message not defined

```
message.guild.members.cache.forEach(member => {
  member.roles.remove("12345678901234");
});
```

Comment: Is this code inside the message event?

Comment: Where exactly are you putting this code in? I don't think the variable `message` is defined in the scope where you are using this snippet.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Role 1"); // if you search for role by id you can remove this line and change role.id to your role ID
message.guild.members.cache.forEach(member => {
if(member.roles.cache.has(role.id) && !member.user.bot) { // !member.user.bot is used to check if user is not a bot
member.roles.remove(role.id)
}
})
```

Comment: It still says that message is not defined

Comment: @SaTaNSouL can you please show full code in your question? And how do you define `message`